# Сравнить числовые значения массивов

Tags: javascript

Есть например 2 массива

```
let a = [1,2,3, 'hello',4,5]
    b = [1,2,3, true, 4, undefined, 6]
```

как сделать функцию которая сравнит в них числовые значения и выведет то которое больше по сумме.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
let a = [1,2,3, 'hello',4,5];
let b = [1,2,3, true, 4, undefined, 6];

function sum(arr)
{
    return arr.reduce((prev, val) => Number.isFinite(val) ? prev + val : prev, 0);
}

let res = Math.max(sum(a), sum(b));
console.log(res);
```

Функцию `sum` можно переписать так:

```
function sum(arr)
{
    //В res_sum будем накапливать сумму.
    let res_sum = 0;
    //Перебираем элементы массива
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        //Если элемент маcсива число, отличное от ±Infinity и NaN, то...
        if (typeof arr[i] === "number" && isFinite(arr[i]))
            res_sum = res_sum + arr[i];
    return res_sum;
}
```

Comment: так как нахожусь на начальном этапе изучения JS не могли бы объяснить  подробнее?  return arr.reduce((p, v) => (typeof v === "number" && isFinite(v)) ? p + v : p, 0);

Comment: @YaroslavBiehliarov, переписал функцию `sum` в развёрнутом виде.

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: `typeof v === "number" && isFinite(v)` ← эквивалентны → `Number.isFinite(v)`

Answer (score 2):

Применяем к обоим массивам следующее:

- метод [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), чтобы отфильтровать все не числа, применяя внутри метод [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) на тип `number`.
- К отфильтрованным данным применяем метод [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), чтобы сакуммулировать все значения в одном в виде суммы.
- Результат применения одинаковых методов сравниваем и узнаём выводим результат